# How to wrap XML but not JSON in Jackson

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I'm trying to serialize a list of `Foo` objects to both XML and JSON using Jackson (this is in a spring-boot web application). This application is implementing an already existing API, so I have to match the existing output format exactly. The formats I'm looking for are as follows:

```xml
<collection>
    <foo>
        <some>value</some>
    </foo>
    <foo>
        <some>other</some>
    </foo>
</collection>
```

```
[
    { "some": "value" },
    { "some": "other" }
]
```

I'm using an API-first approach by writing an OpenAPI 3 spec and generating code from that. The spec for this method defines the return type as an array of `Foo`s:

```
      responses:
        '200':
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/foo'
            application/xml:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/foo'
```

Now when I generate code for this, I get API methods that return `List<Foo>`. This is fine for JSON, generates exactly what I want. For XML, however, I get something like this:

```xml
<List>
  <item>
    <some>value</some>
  </item>
  <item>
    <some>other</some>
  </item>
</List>
```

Since I have to match the existing output format exactly, this isn't going to work. The structure is correct, but the names are not. After Googling around copiously, I found that I should create a wrapper class so I changed the API methods to return `FooCollection` and defined the wrapper class thusly:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="collection")
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "collection")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FooCollection {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "foo")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private final List<Foo> values;

    public FooCollection() {
        this.values = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }

    public FooCollection(List<Foo> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

}
```

Now my output XML looks correct, but the JSON is broken:

```xml
<collection>
    <foo>
        <some>value</some>
    </foo>
    <foo>
        <some>other</some>
    </foo>
</collection>
```

And the JSON:

```
{
    "values": [
        { "some": "value" },
        { "some": "other" }
    ]
}
```

The solution to this, after some more searching, is to add a @JsonValue annotation to the internal `List` in the `FooCollection` class. The result of this is correct JSON, but now the XML is broken again (it actually fails to produce output at all because the below is not valid XML):

```xml
<foo>
    <some>value</some>
</foo>
<foo>
    <some>other</some>
</foo>
```

I would like for the @JsonValue annotation to ONLY take effect when generating JSON... or perhaps a totally different approach since this rabbit hole is getting kind of deep. Ideally, I'd like to make it work while using the `List<Foo>` return type since that's the most semantically correct but I can't seem to find a way to customize the names on the generated XML without writing a wrapper class (which then leads to the problems I'm having).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replacing Jackson for XML serialization with JAXB so I could have more control over the output format. This can be done by registering a custom converter with Spring MVC:

```
    converters.add(new JAXBCollectionWrapperHttpMessageConverter("com.mycompany.myapp.model"));
    converters.add(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
```

The `JAXBCollectionWrapperHttpMessageConverter` is a class that wraps collections into a `JAXBCollection` wrapper class (error handling omitted for brevity):

```
public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, @Nullable MediaType mediaType) {
    return Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz) && canWrite(mediaType);
}

protected void writeToResult(Object o, HttpHeaders headers, Result result) {
    ...
    marshaller.marshal(new JaxbCollectionWrapper<>((Collection<?>)o), result);
}
```

The collection wrapper class looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="collection")
public class JaxbCollectionWrapper<T>{

    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    protected Collection<T> list;

    public JaxbCollectionWrapper(){}

    public JaxbCollectionWrapper(Collection<T> list){
        this.list=list;
    }

    public Collection<T> getList(){
        return list;
    }
}
```